# does wsimport depend on the original source of the wsdl?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, client, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm learning about wsimport.  In the examples I've seen, they show how to generate the wsdl from the server code, and then, how to use wsimport on the wsdl to generate the java client stubs.  Does this imply that in order to use wsimport on the wsdl file, the wsdl file must need to have been originally created using jax-ws?  Or should it work on any wsdl file?

The reason why I'm asking is because I get an error when I run the command:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\wsimport" -s . http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl

I get [ERROR] unexpected <ws:any>

I'm still new at this, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's something wrong with the WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle it works with any wsdl (as long as it follows the standard). Have you tried to download it locally first, in case it wasn't obtained correctly remotely.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error when I download it first.  If you have wsimport installed, can someone try the command I mentioned?  It would be helpful to me to know if there's something wrong with the WSDL or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes I am getting same errors. The wsdl is not valid, there are for example random elements not belonging to schema (<DeprecationVersion> in line 57511), the xs:any elements outside sequence tag. You could try to fix those errors.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm marking this as the answer, but I also tried validating the WSDL, and it shows up as valid.  https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/199177970?version=1    Do you think that the WSDL Analyzer is wrong, or do some "valid" WSDLs not work in wsimport?

Comment: Hi, I tried to use Apache CXF (http://cxf.apache.org/) to generate client from that schema but it also fails in the same place. The 'wsdl' part maybe ok of the file, but the data types definitions are not valid xsd schemas, maybe that is why the wsdl-analyzyer accepts it. The errors are only in 5 places so you can fix those places (and hopefully you dont need those particular services). You can also try Axis2 it is dead project but maybe being old fashion is more forigiving.

Comment: Just following up.  Today, I got a response from the Ebay developer's message board.  They fixed another problem that I mentioned to them.  I tried it again, and still got errors with the xs:any.  This time, it was just one error.  :xs:any was already defined.  This one was easy to solve.  the xs:any was declared in the base class, and then another element inherited from it, and also defined any element of xs:any.  I deleted that one, and the wsimport worked fine.